# Ajax no reconoce parametros como texto solo como número

Tags: ajax

Estoy creando un sistema de información con ajax y PHP en algunas tablas es necesario crear los ID como un conjunto de texto y en otros como número, el problema es que cuando necesito hacer una consulta por id solo reconoce números y cuando selecciono un ID que esta compuesto por letras me tira el siguiente error:

"ACA" es el el valor que tomo y lo pone como si fuera una variable caso contrario ocurre cuando selecciono un id de la tabla que es un número
[image]

> ReferenceError: "ACA" is not defined

Este es el código:

```
<script>
    var tabla_materia;
    function refrescar_materia() {
        tabla_materia.ajax.reload();
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        tabla_materia = $('#tabla_materia').DataTable({
            language: {
                "decimal": ".",
                "emptyTable": "No hay información",
                "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
                "infoPostFix": "",
                "thousands": ",",
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
                "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "processing": "Procesando...",
                "search": "Buscar:",
                "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados",
                "paginate": {
                    "first": "Primero",
                    "last": "Ultimo",
                    "next": "Siguiente",
                    "previous": "Anterior"
                }
            },
            "ajax": {
                "url": "../../modelo/obtener_materias1.php",
                "type": "get",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "idMATERIA"},             
                {"data": "nombre"},
                {"data": "unidades"},
                {"data": "carrera"},
                {"data": "horas_semana"},
                {"data": "creditos"},
                {"data": "ESTATUS"},
                {"data": "idMATERIA", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<a href="#formulario_editar_materia" onclick="obtener_materia_id(' + data.valueOf()+ ')" class="btn-large waves-effect modal-trigger waves-light  orange " ><i class="material-icons centered">edit</i>    </a>';
                    }
                },
                {"data": "idMATERIA", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<a href="#formulario_eliminar_materia" onclick=-"obtener_materia_id_eliminar(' + data.valueOf() + ')" class="btn-large modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light  red"><i class="material-icons centered">delete_forever</i></a>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
    );

    function obtener_materia_id(data) {            
        var datos = {"idMATERIA": data.valueOf()};
        alert(datos.toString());
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../../modelo/obtener_materia_id.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: datos
        });
        request.done(function (data) {
            $("#idmateria_editar").val(data.idMateria);
            $("#nombre_materia_editar").val(data.nombre);
        });
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Hubo un error: " + textStatus);
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Por favor [edit] tu pregunta con un ejemplo de un Id que estés consultando. Al consultarlo, intenta encerrar el ID con comillas dobles *(independientemente de si es un id con o sin letras)*.

Comment: He subido una imagen con el error que sale y he encerrado con comillas el valor que quiero pasar como parámetro sin embargo lo toma como si fuera una variable

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar qué valor tiene `data.valueOf()`?, ¿Por qué no dejas solo `data`?

Comment: porque si dejo solo data  sale el siguiente mensaje: Hubo un error: parsererror

Comment: 1 Suponiendo que selecciono una fila de la tabla que tiene por id un 3 el valor de data.valueOf() es 3 y no hay problema realiza la consulta por ajax pero suponiendo que selecciono una fila que tiene como id ACA-0907 en la consola sale ACA no esta definido es decir que lo reconoce como si fuera el nombre de una variable que aún no está declarada y no como el valor de dicha variable supuse que era el guion pero no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto sucede que en el código en el que mandaba el parámetro tenia esto:

```html
 <a href="#formulario_editar_materia" onclick= "obtener_materia_id('+data.valueOf()+')" class="btn-large waves-effect modal-trigger waves-light  orange " ><i class="material-icons centered">edit</i>    </a>';
```

La solución fue colocar las comillas dentro del método así

```html
<a href="#formulario_editar_materia" onclick= obtener_materia_id("'+data.valueOf()+'") class="btn-large waves-effect modal-trigger waves-light  orange " ><i class="material-icons centered">edit</i>    </a>';
```

Comment: Muy bien, Linux!, *(estaba pensando en sugerirte algo similar, pero, ya sabes, es 31 de diciembre xD )*. Por favor recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.